# Why is IIS Responding with the wrong binding?

Tags: iis-8.5, bindings

I have two websites hosted on a server using IIS.  One is served on port 80 and is simple HTML, no compiled code.  The other is on port 90 and is hosting an ASMX web service.

Every once in a while, when I type the server's IP address into a web browser from another computer, it will actually attempt to serve the web page from the web services site instead of the basic HTML site on port 80, and of course it cannot find the file to serve because it doesn't exist.

This seems to happen every time I need to re-publish the web service.

I can fix it by completing the following procedure:

1. Disable the web service site
2. Visit the basic HTML site normally
3. Re-Enable the web service site

IIS Version: 8.5.9600.16384

I essentially have them named like this:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this so that I don't need to perform that procedure every time I want to re-publish my web service?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Edit~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
I've since deleted the default web site, the issue persists.

Here is an image of the site view showing the only two bindings

[image]

Comment: If you ask a question about bindings, you should tell us what your bindings are. Take a screenshot of the bindings in IIS Manager or use the output of the PowerShell command: `ls IIS:\sites`

Comment: I've set up many an IIS binding configuration.  I'm fairly certain the problem isn't there, but I added an image just in case.

Comment: It's just that the behaviour you are describing is not normal, and incorrect bindings would be the first thing to look at. I would enable Failed Request tracing for both sites and review the requests were it hits the wrong site, maybe that gives you a clue.